# Pivoting table and writing loop to find and fill NaN with specified strings

Tags: python, pandas

(Attaching pictures in case there are issues with the embedded tables)
I have a table that looks like this:
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfmH0.png)

| Submittal Information |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Submission Information |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Lot Information |  |  |  |
| BBL | Submitted by | Company | Phone | Extension | e-mail | date | early compliance | filing status | borough | block | lot | # of buildings on lot |

I want it to look like this: [Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKeEs.png)

| Category | Sub-category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | BBL |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | Submitted by |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | Company |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | Phone |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | Extension |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | e-mail |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | date |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | early compliance |
| Submittal Information | Submission Information | filing status |
| Submittal Information | Lot Information | borough |
| Submittal Information | Lot Information | block |
| Submittal Information | Lot Information | lot |
| Submittal Information | Lot Information | # of buildings on lot |

This involves pivoting the table but also writing a loop that would run through the blank/NaN values and replace them with the associated category and sub-category for each value. Could someone please help me figure out how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Could you let us know where it is that you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

First, simply transpose using `.T`

```
my_df = my_df.T
```

Then make sure all the empty cells are represented with `np.NaN`s
This shows how to replace empty string cells (`""`) with `np.NaN`s:

```
# import numpy as np
# change the 1 to the index of whatever column you need to fill
my_df[my_df[1]==""] = np.NaN
```

After that you can use the `.fillna()` method to fill in the blanks using the cell above

```
my_df = my_df.fillna(method="ffill")
```

Not sure exactly how your dataframe is set up, so might have to play around with the columns and such.